# How to make a sprite with fixed position in cocos2d-iphone v3?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, tiled

How to make a sprite with fixed position in cocos2d-iphone v3 ?I tried to make another one CCNode, and add to it, but it is still scrolled with the whole tile map.

EDIT:
That's my code

```
  CCNode *cNode;
  cNode=[CCNode node];
 [self addChild:cNode];

CCSprite *cSprite;
cSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"cSprite.png"];
   cSprite.position=ccp(80,120);
    [cNode addChild:cSprite];
```

Comment: Don't make that node a child of the tilemap respectively the node that is scrolling.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I added some code to the question. New node is not a child of map layer

Comment: what is self ? 123456789012345